# moving integers from one string to another?

Tags: python, string, iteration

I am looking at adding numbers to a string as python reads through a string.

So if I had a string `a = "253+"`

I would then have an empty string b.

So, how would I have python read the 2, add it to string b, then read the 5 and add it to string b, and then add the 5 and add it to string b, when it hits something that isnt an integer though, it stops the function.

then string b would be `b = "253"`

is there a specific call in an iteration that would ask for integers and then add i to another string?

tl;dr

I want to use an iteration to add numbers from one string to another, which stops when it reaches a non-integer.

string b would be an empty string, and string a would be `a="253+"`

after the call would be done, strng b would equal `b="253"`

I know this sounds like a homework question, but its not. If you need anything else clarified, I would be happy to.

Comment: Just use a regex and split on '[^0-9]'. Or match on '[0-9]+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [201]: import itertools as IT

In [202]: a = "253+9"

In [203]: ''.join(IT.takewhile(str.isdigit, a))
Out[203]: '253'
```

[IT.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) will stop at the first character in `a` which is not a digit.

---

Another way would be to use a regex pattern. You could [split](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.split) the string on non-digits using the pattern `r'\D'`:

```
In [208]: import re

In [209]: re.split(r'\D', a, maxsplit=1)[0]
Out[209]: '253'
```

Comment: Oh wow, I have never heard of itertools. Is that stock on python 3.4.1?

Comment: Yes, itertools is part of the standard library.

Comment: Thank you, I am a bit new to python and this is a really cool tool! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple method for extracting the digits from a string:

```
In [13]: a="253+"

In [14]: ''.join(c for c in a if c.isdigit())
Out[14]: '253'
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear, but is this what you're looking for?

```
a = "123+"
b=""

for c in a:
   try:
     int(c)
     b = b + c
   except ValueError:
     print 'This is not an int ' + c
     break
```

Running this results in this `b` being `123` and breaking on the `+` character. It sounds like the part that's tricky for you at the moment is the `try..except ValueError` bit. Not that I don't have to break the loop when a `ValueError` happens, I could just keep looping over the remaining characters in the string and ignore ones that cannot be parsed into an int

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = "i889i" #Initial value of A
b = "" #Empty string to store result into

for each in a: #iterate through all characters of a
    if each.isdigit(): #check if the current character is a digit
        b += each #append to b if the current character is a digit
    else: #if current character is NOT a digit
        break #break out of for loop

print b #print out result
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this, but it skips over the non digits. should I run it recursively and have it be an else statement where it stops?

Comment: Yea sorry, didn't see that in your question. Above is the modified code.

Comment: I really do like this recursion though. Being new, recursions are so much easier to pick up than iterations, so I really appreciate seeing this recursively!

Comment: The solution that I wrote is iterative. Are you saying you want to see it recursively?

Comment: Oh well, sorry about that. I am brand new to python. I dont need it specifically recursively or iteratively, but I always thougt that if it was an if/else command that it was a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

With the use of the for loop, this is relatively easy. If we use our ASCII knowledge, we know that the ASCII values of the digits range from 48 (which represents 0 as a string) to 57 (which represents 9 as a string).

We can find the ASCII value of a character by using the built in method `ord(x)` where `x` is the character (i.e. `ord('4')` is equal to `52`, the integer).

Now that we have this knowledge, it will be easy to add this to our for-loop. We simply make a for-loop that goes from 0 to the length of the string minus 1. In the for loop, we are going to use the iteration that we are on as an index, find the character at that index in our string, and finally check to see if its `ord` value falls in the range that we want.

This will look something like this:

```
def method(just_a_variable):
    b = ''
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if (#something):
            if (#something):
                b = b+a[i]
    return b
```

Can you fill in the `"#somethings"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generator with a regex and generate them one by one:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='123+456abc789'
>>> nums=(m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'(\d+)', s))
>>> next(nums)
'123'
>>> next(nums)
'456'
>>> next(nums)
'789'
```